# como validar que un PictureBox tenga cargada una imagen especifica

Tags: c#

estoy intentando validar que un Picturebox tenga cargada una imagen especifica (la imagen la agregue a mis recursos del proyecto). He intentado de esta manera:

```
 if (pbnombres.Image == Properties.Resources.x_mark_3_24)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("si hay imagen");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("no hay imagen");
        }
```

pero no me funciona, aunque tenga la imagen que indico en la sentencia del IF me indica el segundo MessageBox ("No hay imagen").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la propiedad `image` de un `PictureBox` se almacena la imagen propiamente dicha (un array de bytes en realidad). No se puede comparar imágenes con un comparador `==`.

Tienes dos soluciones: una sería efectuar una comparación `byte` a `byte` de las imágenes. Para ello podrías usar el método que te pongo a continuación, que hace uso de [`LockBits`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits?view=netframework-4.8). El código no es mio, está tomado de [Determining if 2 images are the same](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/39980):

```
private bool compararImagenes(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2)
{
    bool equals = true;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height);
    BitmapData bmpData1 = bmp1.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp1.PixelFormat);
    BitmapData bmpData2 = bmp2.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp2.PixelFormat);
    unsafe
    {
        byte* ptr1 = (byte*)bmpData1.Scan0.ToPointer();
        byte* ptr2 = (byte*)bmpData2.Scan0.ToPointer();
        int width = rect.Width * 3; // for 24bpp pixel data
        for (int y = 0; equals && y < rect.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                if (*ptr1 != *ptr2)
                {
                    equals = false;
                    break;
                }
                ptr1++;
                ptr2++;
            }
            ptr1 += bmpData1.Stride - width;
            ptr2 += bmpData2.Stride - width;
        }
    }
    bmp1.UnlockBits(bmpData1);
    bmp2.UnlockBits(bmpData2);
    return equals;
}
```

Debes tener en cuenta hace uso de código `unsafe`, por lo que debes activar esa opción a la hora de compilarlo.

La segunda opción es mucho mas sencilla y es la que yo utilizaría. Simplemente, cuando cargues tu imagen en el `PictureBox`, pon su nombre en la propiedad `Tag`. De esta manera puedes comparar si hay algo en `Tag` (asi que hay alguna imagen cargada) y comparar si el nombre de la imagen es el que buscas.

```
pbnombres.Image = Properties.Resources.x_mark_3_24;
pbnombres.Tag = "x_mark_3_24";
....

if (pbnombres.Tag != "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("si hay imagen");
    if (pbnombres.Tag != "x_mark_3_24") 
    {
         MessageBox.Show("la imagen es x_mark_3_24");
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("no hay imagen");
}
```